# Ошибка компилирования на Erlang'е в Debian

Tags: erlang

Компилирую проект на Erlang'е в Debian выводится сообщение

```
# erl -make
{"init terminating in do_boot",{undef,[{make,all_or_nothing,[],[]},{init,start_it,1,[]},{init,start_em,1,[]}]}}  
Определяемый пользователем сигнал 2
```

В чем причина?

Answer (score 1):

> undef

Это значит что эрланг не нашёл функции или модуля с такими именами, вот и всё. Возможно модуль просто недоступен, не подгрузился. Либо вы ошиблись в имени функции.